# Installshield is not correctly reading an Environment Variable set earlier by a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, installshield

I am invoking a PowerShell Script from InstallShield - this script sets up two environment variables that each contain the file version of an installed file

The PS Script contains

```
$fileversion1 = (Get-Command '<File1>').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("File_Version_Installed_VCS",$fileversion1,"Machine")
$fileversion2 = (Get-Command '<File2>').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("File_Version_Installing_VCS",$fileversion2,"Machine")
```

And it is invoked from Installshield script via

```
My_AddToLog("Start - set up execution permissions for PowerShell Scripts");

__LaunchAppAndWait("powershell"," Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass"); 

: // Other lines of code, then later

 __LaunchAppAndWait("powershell",".\\GetFileVersion.ps1"); 

: // Other lines of code, then later

    if !(GetEnvVar("File_Version_Installed_VCS",sv_Installed_VCS_version ) < 0) then
       if !(GetEnvVar("File_Version_Installing_VCS",sv_Installing_VCS_version) < 0) then
          nvResult = StrCompare (sv_Installing_VCS_version,sv_Installed_VCS_version);
          :// other lines of code
       else
         My_AddToLog("File_Version_Installing_VCS envar not defined - cannot compare versions. Do 
         not overwrite Installed VCS version");
     else
         My_AddToLog("File_Version_Installed_VCS envar not defined - cannot compare versions. Do 
         not overwrite Installed VCS version");
     endif;
```

The first time I run the program, I have verified via the log file that these environment variables are set by the PS1 script ( also checked before that the Envars did not previously exist), and that this is done before the later check on the environment variables is done. Looking at the log file output

> ```
> 8-10-2021 12:41:18 - Start - set up execution permissions for PowerShell Scripts
> 8-10-2021 12:41:18 -  Executing Command powershell  Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
> 8-10-2021 12:41:27 -  Command SUCCESS 
> :
> 8-10-2021 12:54:10 -  Executing Command powershell .\GetFileVersion.ps1
> 8-10-2021 12:54:20 - Waiting for Command to Complete 
> 8-10-2021 12:54:27 -  Command SUCCESS 
> :
> ```

And I have also  checked that the envars are setup around this time (approximately)
But then later

> 8-10-2021 12:56:06 - File_Version_Installed_VCS envar not defined -
> cannot compare versions. Do not overwrite Installed VCS version

However after program terminates, then when I run the program again the envars are this time correctly detected ( with the values set from the previous run).
So this looks to be a timing issue - it seems that the installshield GetEnvVar call cannot detect the environment variables even though they were set about 1.5 seconds previously. I have tried adding further delays between the setting of the envars and subsequent reading of them but it makes no difference. I believe the GetEnvVar will have to open a CMD window to read the Environment Variables, and somehow this is not able to read the previously set values - this can only work when starting a new program run.
Any ideas on how to overcome this would be much appreciated. May thanks in advance.

Comment: The contents of my PowerShell script were not correctly shown. they are

Comment: The lines are
$fileversion1 = (Get-Command "file1").FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("File_Version_Installed_VCS",$fileversion1,"Machine")

Answer (score 0):

$fileversion1 = (Get-Command '').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("File_Version_Installed_VCS",$fileversion1,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
$fileversion2 = (Get-Command '').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("File_Version_Installing_VCS",$fileversion2,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)